# Calling one entry at a time from a dataset in order

Tags: r

I have a simple data set (lets just call it data) containing 100 values and i wish to call them one at a time for entry into an equation (i cant post this particular equation here).

The problem im having is that from the equation there needs to be two outputs (probability), and when i call the data set directly, it does not give the desired output. Entering the numbers manually from the dataset gives the correct output (checked manually).

There are two streams of input as evidenced by the two outputs, is there something simple im missing regarding the input of a simple dataset?

**EDIT** the dataset which just a sample of 100 numbers needs to be entered in the equation i have. another value is to be subtracted from each entry in the dataset so unfortunately the solution below wont work.

the equation has two main sets of information feeding it in the form of two means, and other global parameters. From this, two prob values are calculated, one for each option.

However linking the above 100 value matrix results in 100 values being created which make no sense anyway. Putting in the first value manually from the matrix into the equation results in the correct output - 2 values (checked by hand)

Thanks

Comment: We can't help you without a much clearer understanding of your code and question.  If you have written your function properly, you should be able to pass it a vector and have it return a list of outputs.  However, without knowing anything about what you have written... can you create an example with a non-proprietary equation? can you show us how you were "entering the number manually"?

Comment: Is your “data set” a `data.frame` or a simple vector? Why do you have to pass the values to the equation one after the other, instead of doing a proper vectorized computation? In what way should a single equation yield more than one output? SOunds like two columns in a resulting `data.frame` to me, is that what you want? When “it does not give the desired output”, in what way is that output incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a vector of 100 values and a function that returns two values for each invocation then this should work:

```
res <- sapply( vec, f)
```

You should get either a list or a two column matrix depending on what type of returned object the `f`-function gives you.